# How fix test for change password view (Django REST Framework)?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, django-testing

In view, the test does not take the request.data as an element of DRF.
I have this view:

```
class ChangePasswordView(UpdateAPIView):

    serializer_class = ChangePasswordSerializer
    model = UserInfo
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response(status=200)

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.request.user
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            if not self.object.check_password(serializer.data.get("old_password")):
                return Response(
                    {"old_password": ["Wrong password"]},
                    status=400
                )
            self.object.set_password(serializer.data.get("new_password"))
            self.object.save()
            return Response("Success", status=200)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

and I have this test method:

```
def test_change_password(self):
    client = APIClient()
    self.client.post('/api/user/login/', self.data, follow=True)
    self.client.login(username="testuser", password="secret")
    request = client.put('/api/user/change_password/', self.new_data)

    self.assertEqual(
         request, '<Response status_code=200, "application/json">'
    )
```

where data:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.data = {
        'username': 'testuser',
        'password': 'secret'
    }

    self.new_data = {
        'old_password': 'secret',
        'new_password': 'other_secret'
    }

    User.objects.create_user(**self.data)
```

Why does the test stop at reqest.data in serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are getting the user wrong.

This might solve your issue:

```
from rest_framework import status

class ChangePasswordView(UpdateAPIView):

serializer_class = ChangePasswordSerializer
model = UserInfo
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    user = request.user
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        if not self.object.check_password(serializer.data.get("old_password")):
            msg = _("Wrong old password.")
            raise ValidationError(msg)

        user.set_password(serializer.data.get("new_password"))
        user.save()
        return Response("Success", status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    msg = _('Something went wrong while reading the passwords')
    raise ValidationError(msg)
```

I am using the imported `status` from `rest_framework` in order to handle the error codes more easily.

Is there any specific reason you are using `put`? I have changed it to `post`. When making this API call (change password), you should use post.

You can easily get the user with `request.user` and then use the variable `user` inside put function to set the password and save it.

Regarding the test case, this could be a help and/or work for you. If it doesn't work, you might need to change it a bit.

```
from rest_framework import status

def test_change_password(self):
    client = APIClient()
    self.client.post('/api/user/login/', self.data, follow=True)
    self.client.login(username="testuser", password="secret")
    response = self.post('/api/user/change_password/', self.new_data)

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```